# Change data-processing-sources attribute of HTML canvas? (running Processing.js on canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing

Okay so I want to have a webpage with one canvas where I choose which Processing.js project I load with a javascript function.

Right now what I'm trying to do is at first have this canvas:

```
<canvas id="can1" data-processing-sources='empty.pde'></canvas>
```

which is an empty Processing project. But then I click a button which runs this javascript function:

```
document.getElementById('can1').data-processing-sources="circles.pde";
```

So that I change the source from the empty project to circles.pde. But javascript won't let me change the data-processing-sources like that; it gives me

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

On the doc.gelement.data-processing-sources=circles.pde line

Is it not possible to change the source of the canvas like this? If not what other options do I have to reach the same goal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "JavaScript won't let me do this"? Do you get an error? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, yes, guess I should have been more specific. I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" on the line where I try to change the data-processing-sources to circles.pde

Comment: I don't think you can access data- attributes like  that. Instead, try this: `document.getElementById('can1').setAttribute("data-processing-sources", "circles.pde");` More info [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Comment: Hmmm that gets rid of the error but now the button doesn't do anything at all it seems. Here's where I'm running it: http://enewsom.com/home.php. I also tried document.getElementById('can1').dataset.processing-sources="circles.pde"; but that gave me the same 'invalid left-hand side' error.